# Posso atualizar a versão do GIT sem perder meus repositórios?

Tags: git, atualização, repository, versionamento

Meu git tem a versão 1.9.5 e a versão atual é a 2.7.0 eu posso instalar a nova versão sem perder meus dados? Pois tenho uma serie de repositórios com essa versão antiga!! O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode atualizar a versão do GIT sem nenhum problema, pois os dados de cada repositório ficam armazenados dentro do diretório de cada um deles, estes dados são armazenados no diretório oculto `.git`.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção! Posso confiar? Já baixei o anova versão hein!! Só falta executar!! Você já fez isso antes?

Comment: Pode confiar sim, eu já atualizei o GIT várias vezes e nunca tive problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Em meus servidores (Debian, CentOs, Gentoo...) sempre atualizei sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Só pro seu conhecimento, respostas de só uma linha vão parar na fila de análise de *"Publicações de baixa qualidade"* onde podemos votar pra deletar (não é o caso agora)... tenho certeza que não quer seu nome associado a isso... o guia [answer] tem mais detalhes

Comment: Valeu pela dica, realmente eu não sabia desta "regra" a respeito do tamanho das respostas. É que geralmente tento ser o mais objetivo possível, maaaaassss... heheheh. Realmente, muito obrigado. ;)

Comment: É... na verdade, olhando a resposta aceita, ela explica bem melhor *porque* pode atualizar sem problema... Olhando de novo, até votei o comentário do Leonardo e sua resposta. É só que acho que ela não acrescenta nada em termos de técnica e podia ser perfeitamente um comentário. Sorry, nada pessoal.